How to avoid and Why Flux.collectList() make request waiting longer
I'm tring build a resful api with Spring WebFlux, and I found when I making Flux Object be restful would make request‘s Waiting time longer, but I read another thread said that collectList() is not blocking thread.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class TestController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var articleService: ArticleService

    // Used for wrapping response to RESTFul
    val mapper: (Any) -> Mono<Any> = { it: Any -> Mono.just(RestResponse(200, "success", it)) }

    @GetMapping("/a")
    fun getArticles() = articleService.queryAll()

    @GetMapping("/b")
    fun getArticles2() = articleService.queryAll()
        .collectList() 
//      .flatMap(mapper)   If without collectList(), cant warp response
}

Requesting /test/a
Requesting /test/b
In addition, I'm trying to think to create a empty Mono object and use Callback function to finish  wraping the response to restful but seems dont work
